# ignore multiline comments in text file when reading in python

Tags: python, count, readfile

i'm trying to count how many lines of code are in multiple text files in a directory using a python script. I've come up with the following method, but it only works if the comment is on one line not multiline. is there a way to do this?

```
def remove_comments(line):
    if line.startswith('/*') or line.endsswith('*/'):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

count = sum(remove_comments(line) for line in f if line.strip())
```

Comment: What language? Some allow nested block comments.

Comment: It is better to use a static analysis tool. There are too many corner cases to handle - mid-line comment ends, commented out block comments, blank lines counted etc

Comment: @chepner it is .sas files dont think there are any nested comments

Comment: @Marat do you have any suggestions on a tool to use?

Comment: unfortunately, not for sas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty hack could be to use a global variable:

```py
with open("test", 'r') as f_in:
    f = f_in.readlines()

is_in_comment = False

def remove_comments(line):
    global is_in_comment
    line = line.strip()

    if line.startswith('/*'):
        is_in_comment = True
        return 0
    elif line.endswith('*/'):
        is_in_comment = False
        return 0

    return 0 if is_in_comment else 1

count = sum(remove_comments(line) for line in f if line.strip())
```

This assumes you can't have a `*/` without previous `/*` however. This code returns 3 for the following `test` file:

```
That is one line
Another
/* Comment
Other comment
End comment */
Final line, not a comment
```

Comment: sorry have just seen this!  I've tried this and it doesnt cover comments that span over multiple lines so for example /* line 1 line 2 line 3*/

Comment: It is possible that it comes from the fact that even though you test whether `line.strip()` is nil, you don't call `remove_comments` with `line.strip()`. Hence, it is called with something like `this is a line */\n`, which makes `line.endswith('*/')` return False. I've updated the code to take this case into account and tested it on a sample file, can you test it?

Comment: thank you so much! saved me a lot of headache as couldn't get my head around it, just added an elif statement for a single line comment